# Monit is getting false negative for mongo http host checkup

Tags: mongodb, monit, mmonit

I am trying to create a monit config file to monitor if mongodb is running.

Here's my config file.

```
check process mongod with pidfile /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
   group mongodb
   start program = "/sbin/start mongod"
   stop  program = "/sbin/stop mongod"
   if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 27017 protocol http
     and request "/" with timeout 10 seconds then restart
```

I always get the following error and it restarts mongodb.

```
  port response time           FAILED to [localhost]:27017 type TCP/IP protocol HTTP
```

I checked and verified mongodb running. I event tried connecting to mongodb using curl. Here's the command I executed to verify http connection to the mongo is working.

```
curl -v localhost:27017
```

Here's the output I am getting.

```
* Rebuilt URL to: localhost:27017/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 27017 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:27017
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
>
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 200 OK
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 85
<
It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.
* Closing connection 0
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

The same config file is working on ubuntu 14.4, but it does not working ubuntu 18.4.

Answer (score 0):

By some reason I had false negative response for MongoDB on CentOS 6.10

That fixed with new protocol check, that implemented in Monit

```
  if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 27017 protocol mongodb
     then restart
```

Notice new protocol name **mongodb**

That simply works fine

Comment: Great, I will try it. I had changed monit config to execute mongo connect command to test mongo working.